# SQL retrieving max value plus corresponding another column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have following table in my database

```
      A        B          C       D          E
    2009    db1234      12345   1234567     3000
    2010    db1235      34567   1234567     3100
    2011    cn2345      23456   2345678     2800
    2010    db1236      12345   1234567     3100
    2012    db1237      34567   1234567     2800
```

if I do max function on table A I would get 2012.
I want query to return A and corresponding C column value i.e. 34567, In SQL.

Answer (score 4):

To get a value(s) of corresponding column(s) along with the value of the column to which an aggregate function is being applied you need to group by that column(s). Another approach is to use one of the [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), whether it [row_number()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions169.htm#SQLRF06100) or [rank()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions154.htm#SQLRF00690) they behave differently but under certain circumstances they may produce the same result. Here are a couple of examples:

```
SQL> with t1 (A, B, C, D, E) as(
  2  select  2009, 'db1234', 12345, 1234567, 3000  from dual union all
  3  select  2010, 'db1235', 34567, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  4  select  2011, 'cn2345', 23456, 2345678, 2800  from dual union all
  5  select  2010, 'db1236', 12345, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  6  select  2012, 'db1237', 34567, 1234567, 2800  from dual
  7  )
  8  select max(a) maxa
  9       , c
 10    from t1
 11  group by c
 12  order by 1
 13  ;
```

Result:

```
      MAXA          C
---------- ----------
      2010      12345
      2011      23456
      2012      34567
```

If you want to return just first row (ordering is important)  you can use `rownum` pseudocolumn to filter result:

```
SQL> with t1 (A, B, C, D, E) as(
  2  select  2009, 'db1234', 12345, 1234567, 3000  from dual union all
  3  select  2010, 'db1235', 34567, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  4  select  2011, 'cn2345', 23456, 2345678, 2800  from dual union all
  5  select  2010, 'db1236', 12345, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  6  select  2012, 'db1237', 34567, 1234567, 2800  from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9    from (select max(a) maxa
 10               , c
 11            from t1
 12           group by c
 13           order by 1 desc
 14  )
 15  where rownum = 1
 16  ;
```

Result:

```
      MAXA          C
---------- ----------
      2012      34567
```

Second approach is to use `row_number` analytical function.

```
SQL> with t1 (A, B, C, D, E) as(
  2  select  2009, 'db1234', 12345, 1234567, 3000  from dual union all
  3  select  2010, 'db1235', 34567, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  4  select  2011, 'cn2345', 23456, 2345678, 2800  from dual union all
  5  select  2010, 'db1236', 12345, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  6  select  2012, 'db1237', 34567, 1234567, 2800  from dual
  7  )
  8  select a
  9       , b
 10       , c
 11       , d
 12       , e
 13    from (select a
 14               , b
 15               , c
 16               , d
 17               , e
 18               , row_number() over(partition by c order by a desc) rn
 19    from t1
 20  )
 21  where rn = 1
 22  ;
```

Result:

```
         A B               C          D          E
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
      2010 db1236      12345    1234567       3100
      2011 cn2345      23456    2345678       2800
      2012 db1237      34567    1234567       2800
```

If you do not want to group by any column you can write a similar query(here analytical version of `max` function is used):

```
SQL> with t1 (A, B, C, D, E) as(
  2  select  2009, 'db1234', 12345, 1234567, 3000  from dual union all
  3  select  2010, 'db1235', 34567, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  4  select  2011, 'cn2345', 23456, 2345678, 2800  from dual union all
  5  select  2010, 'db1236', 12345, 1234567, 3100  from dual union all
  6  select  2012, 'db1237', 34567, 1234567, 2800  from dual
  7  )
  8  select *
  9     from(select a
 10               , b
 11               , c
 12               , d
 13               , e
 14               , max(a) over() mx
 15           from t1
 16          ) q
 17    where q.a = q.mx
 18  ;
```

Result:

```
         A B               C          D          E         MX
---------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      2012 db1237      34567    1234567       2800       2012
```

Comment: Of course, if exactly one row (the one containing the maximum value) is required, there's no need to perform aggregating (in this particular case). You can just fetch the topmost row as sorted by `a DESC`. Other than that, this is a very nicely elaborated answer, +1